# Auto click a custom hyperlink when page load using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a link and would like to auto click it to open an popup windows to play an video.

The link is like as

```
<a rel="wp-video-lightbox" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxxxxx&amp;width=640&amp;height=480" title="">Watch Movie</a>
```

How do I do it in jQuery?

Best regards,

Kelvin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do something like this:

```
<a rel="wp-video-lightbox" href="" title="">Watch Movie</a>

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a[rel="your-rel"]').get(0).click();trigger('click');
});
```

**UPDATE:**
updated the code for your needs, now you only have to change the "rel" attribute.

Comment: How can I code to auto click the <a> with "rel=" instead of adding an id? It is because the link is generated by 3rd party and I have no right to modify it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Attribute Equals Selector [name="value"]](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) to get element then use `.get()` to refer to DOM element.

Use

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[rel="wp-video-lightbox"]') //Get element using rel attribute
        .get(0) //Get DOM element
        .click(); //Click
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var rel = $('a[rel="wp-video-lightbox"]');
        rel[0].click();
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6pVjB/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var href = $('a[rel="wp-video-lightbox"]').attr('href');
    window.location.href = href;
});
</script>
```

Comment: I am not going to change the page, just click the <a> then a popup windows will be showed.